# capture Exceptions while inserting foreign key in spring

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I have two tables named Table A with primary key A1, Table B with primary key B1.
i have another table Table X which stores primary key of Table A and Table B.

Table X(A1,B1)

While inserting new record in Table X, if primary key of Table A is not present in the provided input then it should throw an exception specifying that "Table A is not having A1 record". in the sameway for Table B .

I need to achieve in spring as my project is built purely on spring.

Thanks ,
Stephen666

Comment: We were not using Hibernate. So thats y i need to have code in spring jdbc.

Comment: Have you tried inserting into TableX when there is no record in Table A? Try it and you will see what exception gets thrown. Then you can catch it.

Comment: it throws  DataIntegrityVoilationException. But i need to capture the exception such a way that it should must tell like " A1 primary key is not present in Table 1 . this i need to bring upto UI.  similarly for Table B.

Comment: I would suggest writing a method like `boolean doesRecordExistInTableA(int id)`, and you call this in your `catch (DataIntegrityVoilationException e)` block.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring with jpa (ex: hibernate) and mapped the entity classes properly then you will get DataIntegrityViolationException thrown by spring itself, in those scenarios.

Comment: We were not using Hibernate. So thats y i need to have code in spring jdbc.